# PHP-Structure overview messy project

Tags: php, dictionary, project

Im looking for an prefferably automated tool that generates a diagram over the 
structure of a laaaaaaaaaarge php project, files with 10 000 lines of code in them.
Mixed php with html with css and javascript here and there.

Need the ones in charge to realize that the project needs refactoring.
Theres not really any oop in this project so some kind of class diagram overview
would only show a small part of the project since its 99% functions.

Anyone that could point me in the right direction to sort out this mess? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will truly help but it's too big for a comment..

There is a program called [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) which can generate documentation from php source files, now bear with me..

There is an [extension](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html) to this program that generates <strike>structographs(?)</strike> structograms based on the source too, it may be of some help.

Failing that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193/how-do-you-justify-refactoring-work-to-your-penny-pinching-boss) and maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333133/how-do-you-convince-your-manager-that-your-project-needs-a-huge-refactoring) can offer you some advice on how to get the message across.

Comment: Checked that one out before, not quite what im looking for im afraid. It would be perfect to have started the project with the help of doxygen though :/

Comment: Added some links to similar situations